# I'm trying to do an NFA->DFA translation in C# using powerset construction and handling large ranges introduced by unicode

Tags: c#, dfa, nfa

I successfully implemented powerset construction (huffman minimization, i think) over a DFA using single character values, but I've modified the FA states to be able to handle unicode ranges.
Now they look like this:

```
sealed partial class FA
{
    public readonly Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int,int>,FA> InputTransitions = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int,int>,FA>();
    public readonly HashSet<FA> EpsilonTransitions = new HashSet<FA>();
    public int AcceptSymbol = -1;
    public bool IsAccepting = false;
```

My characters are stored as UTF-32 valued integers so I don't have to deal with surrogates
Each Input Transition can take a range with a starting and ending UTF-32 value encoded as a keyvaluepair

I've modified my ToDfa() routine (previously working for single values) to work with ranges, but it doesn't work right. NormalizeSortedRangeList() takes a presorted list of keyvaluepair ranges and combines overlapping ranges (replacing multiple overlapping ranges with a single range encompassing them all). _SetComparer just does unordered comparisons on lists and collections

```
public FA ToDfa(IProgress<FAProgress> progress=null)
{
    // if it's already a DFA we don't need to do this transformation.
    // however, we still need to clone the state machine it because
    // the consumer expects a copy, not the original state.
    if (IsDfa)
        return Clone();
    // The DFA states are keyed by the set of NFA states they represent.
    var dfaMap = new Dictionary<List<FA>, FA>(_SetComparer.Default);

    var unmarked = new HashSet<FA>();

    // compute the epsilon closure of the initial state in the NFA
    var states = new List<FA>();
    FillEpsilonClosure(states);

    // create a new state to represent the current set of states. If one 
    // of those states is accepting, set this whole state to be accepting.
    FA dfa = new FA();
    var al = new List<int>();
    // find the accepting symbols for the current states
    foreach (var fa in states)
        if (fa.IsAccepting)
            if (!al.Contains(fa.AcceptSymbol))
                al.Add(fa.AcceptSymbol);
    // here we assign the appropriate accepting symbol
    int ac = al.Count;
    //if (1 == ac)
    if(0<ac)
        dfa.AcceptSymbol = al[0];
    //else if (1 < ac)
    //  dfa.AcceptSymbol = al[0]; // could throw, just choose the first one
    dfa.IsAccepting = 0 < ac;

    FA result = dfa; // store the initial state for later, so we can return it.

    // add it to the dfa map
    dfaMap.Add(states, dfa);

    // add it to the unmarked states, signalling that we still have work to do.
    unmarked.Add(dfa);
    bool done = false;
    var j = 0;
    while (!done)
    {
        if(null!=progress)
        {
            progress.Report(new FAProgress(FAStatus.DfaTransform, j));
        }
        done = true;
        // a new hashset used to hold our current key states
        var mapKeys = new HashSet<List<FA>>(dfaMap.Keys, _SetComparer.Default);
        foreach (var mapKey in mapKeys)
        {
            dfa = dfaMap[mapKey];
            if (unmarked.Contains(dfa))
            {
                // when we get here, mapKey represents the epsilon closure of our 
                // current dfa state, which is indicated by kvp.Value

                // build the transition list for the new state by combining the transitions
                // from each of the old states

                // retrieve every possible input for these states
                var inputs = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>();
                foreach (var state in mapKey)
                {
                    foreach (var trns in state.InputTransitions)
                        if(!inputs.Contains(trns.Key))
                            inputs.Add(trns.Key);
                }
                inputs.Sort((x, y) => { 
                    var c = x.Key.CompareTo(y.Key);
                    if (0 == c)
                        c = x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value);
                    return c;

                });
                RangeUtility.NormalizeSortedRangeList(inputs);
                // for each input, create a new transition
                foreach (var input in inputs)
                {
                    var acc = new List<int>();
                    var ns = new List<FA>();
                    foreach (var state in mapKey)
                    {

                        foreach (var trns in state.InputTransitions)
                        {
                            if (RangeUtility.Intersects(trns.Key, input))
                            {
                                FA dst = trns.Value;
                                foreach (var d in dst.FillEpsilonClosure())
                                {
                                    //  add the accepting symbols
                                    if (d.IsAccepting)
                                        if (!acc.Contains(d.AcceptSymbol))
                                            acc.Add(d.AcceptSymbol);
                                    if (!ns.Contains(d))
                                        ns.Add(d);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    FA ndfa;
                    if (!dfaMap.TryGetValue(ns, out ndfa))
                    {
                        ac = acc.Count;
                        ndfa = new FA(0 < ac);
                        // assign the appropriate accepting symbol
                        //if (1 == ac)
                        if(0<ac)
                            ndfa.AcceptSymbol = acc[0];
                        //else if (1 < ac)
                        //  ndfa.AcceptSymbol = acc[0]; // could throw, instead just set it to the first state's accept
                        dfaMap.Add(ns, ndfa);
                        // work on this new state
                        unmarked.Add(ndfa);
                        done = false;
                    }
                    dfa.InputTransitions.Add(input, ndfa);
                }
                // we're done with this state
                unmarked.Remove(dfa);
            }
        }
        ++j;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works kind of, but not really. The issue is my range handling is bad, but I can't quite figure how. I've dumped GraphViz dot for my states but I can't make much sense of where it's going wrong.

I tried looking at Brics (Java) and Fare (C#) but I couldn't make much sense of their NFA->DFA routines which create a bunch of junk states they then remove.

I'm not entirely sure what I'll need to clarify for you, the reader as I just don't understand the problem domain well enough, so please post any questions you have for me in the comments and I'll do my best.

Full source is available here https://github.com/codewitch-honey-crisis/Rolex/tree/master/Rolex/FA

How in the heck do you do ranges in powerset construction? Several libraries do it, none that i can figure out

Comment: What exactly is the question? Right now, it's a broad request for debugging help. In order for that to be on topic, you'll need to provide sample inputs and expected vs. actual outputs, for both working and non-working cases. That will help narrow the focus.

Comment: This seems like a really good time to add a unit test project to your solution and build a full suite of unit tests. I can see the potential for regressions as you attempt to dial in the range handling. It will also help others understand what it should be doing.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. It's not a debugging problem. I wish it was. It's a problem with the way I'm even going about it. It's just wrong. I don't know what the right way is, I just know that there is one. The question is "how in the heck does one do powerset construction with ranges instead of individual characters?"

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to adopt Fare/bric's solution to my own code

```
// Portions of this code adopted from Fare, itself adopted from brics
// original copyright notice included.
// This is the only file this applies to.

/*
 * dk.brics.automaton
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2001-2011 Anders Moeller
 * All rights reserved.
 * http://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare/
 * Original Java code:
 * http://www.brics.dk/automaton/
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *    documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 3. The name of the author may not be used to endorse or promote products
 *    derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE AUTHOR ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.
 * IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
 * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT
 * NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF
 * THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */

public static FA _Determinize(FA fa, IProgress<FAProgress> progress = null)
{
    if (null != progress)
        progress.Report(new FAProgress(FAStatus.DfaTransform, 0));
    var p = new HashSet<int>();
    var closure = new List<FA>();
    fa.FillClosure(closure);
    for(int ic=closure.Count,i=0;i<ic;++i)
    {
        var ffa = closure[i];
        p.Add(0);
        foreach (var t in ffa.InputTransitions)
        {
            p.Add(t.Key.Key);
            if (t.Key.Value < 0x10ffff)
            {
                p.Add((t.Key.Value + 1));
            }
        }
    }

    var points = new int[p.Count];
    p.CopyTo(points, 0);
    Array.Sort(points);

    var comparer = _SetComparer.Default;

    var sets = new Dictionary<ICollection<FA>, ICollection<FA>>(comparer);
    var working = new Queue<ICollection<FA>>();
    var dfaMap = new Dictionary<ICollection<FA>, FA>(comparer);
    var initial = fa.FillEpsilonClosure();
    sets.Add(initial, initial);
    working.Enqueue(initial);
    var result = new FA();
    foreach(var afa in initial)
    {
        if(afa.IsAccepting)
        {
            result.IsAccepting = true;
            result.AcceptSymbol = afa.AcceptSymbol;
            break;
        }
    }
    dfaMap.Add(initial, result);
    var j = 1;
    while (working.Count > 0)
    {
        ICollection<FA> s = working.Dequeue();
        var ecs = FillEpsilonClosure(s);
        FA dfa;
        dfaMap.TryGetValue(s, out dfa);
        foreach (FA q in ecs)
        {
            if (q.IsAccepting)
            {
                dfa.IsAccepting = true;
                dfa.AcceptSymbol = q.AcceptSymbol;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            var set = new HashSet<FA>();
            foreach (FA c in ecs)
            {
                foreach (var trns in c.InputTransitions)
                {
                    if (trns.Key.Key <= points[i] && points[i] <= trns.Key.Value)
                    {
                        foreach (var efa in trns.Value.FillEpsilonClosure())
                            set.Add(trns.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!sets.ContainsKey(set))
            {
                sets.Add(set, set);
                working.Enqueue(set);
                dfaMap.Add(set, new FA());
            }

            FA dst;
            dfaMap.TryGetValue(set, out dst);
            int first = points[i];
            int last;
            if (i + 1 < points.Length)
                last = (points[i + 1] - 1);
            else
                last = 0x10ffff;
            dfa.InputTransitions.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(first, last), dst);
        }
        if (null != progress)
            progress.Report(new FAProgress(FAStatus.DfaTransform, j));

        ++j;
    }
    // remove dead transitions
    foreach(var ffa in result.FillClosure())
    {
        var itrns = new List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<int, int>, FA>>(ffa.InputTransitions);
        ffa.InputTransitions.Clear();
        foreach(var trns in itrns)
        {
            if(null!=trns.Value.FirstAcceptingState)
            {
                ffa.InputTransitions.Add(trns.Key, trns.Value);
            }
        }
        if (null != progress)
            progress.Report(new FAProgress(FAStatus.DfaTransform, j));
        ++j;
    }
        return result;
}
```